# Facebook: sharing a Play Store link using the Share Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I share a link using the share dialog from the Facebook Android SDK. My code looks like this:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
          .setName("My app name")
          .setCaption("A caption")
          .setDescription("My description...")
          .setLink("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.company.myapp")
          .setPicture("http://link_to_picture")
          .build();
```

As I want users to be redirected to my app's Play Store page, I put this url in the link. But in that case, the post doesn't show the information I specified (name, caption, description). Instead, it shows the app name specified in the Play Store, with a "download it" caption (the picture is ok).

When I set another link, this issue doesn't occur: the post displays the name, caption and description as expected. Why can't I put my own text with a Play Store link?

**EDIT**

I tried using App Links. So I created an App Link object with this:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/app/app_link_hosts \
-F access_token="APP_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F name="My app link" \
-F android=' [
    {
      "url" : "myapp://share/1234",
      "package" : "com.company.myapp",
      "app_name" : "My app",
    },
 ]' \
-F web=' {
    "should_fallback" : false,
  }'
```

And I got this url: https://fb.me/494085890722766

Now, the post looks good, but clicking on it from Facebook app when my app is not installed pops up a chooser that proposes to open the link in a browser or install the application, which is not a good user experience.

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how you got this "https://fb.me/494085890722766" URL ? What do we need to do get App Link? Steps for it or procedure? Do I need to create a new html page on my website for the same?

Comment: How do we run the curl code? what is APP_ACCESS_TOKEN and what to write in place of "myapp://share/1234"

Comment: To create your App Link object, follow instructions described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api You get your app token, read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens Curl is a command line tool that you can use to make HTTP POST requests.

Comment: @Superthib, one quick question, what did you do with the generated url, "fb.me/494085890722766"? the documentation seem to suggest nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a workaround using App Links, which is detailed here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api

I created my App Link object **without** any "-F web" parameter, like this:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/app/app_link_hosts \
-F access_token="APP_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F name="My app link" \
-F android=' [
    {
      "url" : "myapp://share/1234",
      "package" : "com.company.myapp",
      "app_name" : "My app",
    },
 ]'
```

However, I don't understand why Facebook API works in a so weird way. It's a complicated solution to a simple issue.

Comment: I've used this method to post my app on fb and its working (Thanks). But if the app is installed and i tap on the shared post in the fb app, i get the error "There's a problem opening this app." I want my app to open if the shared post is tapped, any suggestions ?

Comment: No worries, i got it work. For future reference, here's what I did:
I added this code to the activity's tag in the Android Manifest
'<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> <data android:scheme="myapp" /> </intent-filter>'

Comment: @superthib What is the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN here and how we can get it in android. Please guide me. Even i have the same issue.

Comment: Read more about APP_ACCESS_TOKEN here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

Answer (score 0):

Replace your link with

```
 .setLink("market://details?id=com.company.myapp")
```

[See this link](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html)

Comment: This should only be used from an Android app, and my link is intended to be displayed in Facebook. However, I tried this and I got the following error from the Facebook SDK: "link URL is not properly formatted".

Comment: I see. How about this then? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

Comment: I tried this, which is a little better: the post looks good, but clicking on it from Facebook app shows a dialog that proposes to open the link in a browser or install the application. The first choice redirects to facebook login from the web, before redirecting to Play Store, and the second redirects directly to Play Store... Not a really good user experience, but it may be acceptable.

Comment: Can you let me know what tags you're using for app links, and a sample url? It shouldn't pop up a chooser. Also, what version of the FB app do you have?

Comment: I updated my question with app link details. My Facebook version is 10.0.0.28.27

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I disable DeepLink in Facebook Developer Console and it work well.

Comment: Where is this option located?